# Can I control a solenoid valve below its nominal voltage?

Tags: voltage, pwm, heat, solenoid-valve

I need to control the following 2 ways direct solenoid valve ("Series 252 D01") :

https://www.emerson.com/documents/automation/catalog-series-252-dental-manifolds-asco-en-6779448.pdf

It is rated at 24 VDC. If I apply this voltage, the valves opens (it is normally closed) and it consumes approx. 170 mA (meaning its power is 4 W).

But the valve also opens up at approx. 15 V (it consumes 100 mA -> 1.5 W). Once it is opened, I can go down to 3 V (it consumes 0.18 mA -> 0.5 W), and closes at 2 V.

Because the solenoid heats up at 24 VDC (approx. 50 °C after 15 min), I was wondering if I could control it as follows : I open it at 24 VDC and maintain its opening by reducing the voltage to 3 V. I can achieve this behavior with a PWM and a transistor.

Do you think it is a good or a bad idea ? What could go wrong ? Is it something which is usually done or not at all ?

If not, is it possible to reduce the heat while maintaining the proper functionning of the valve ?

Thanks.

Comment: It is always a bad idea to be below/higher or too near of limits specified by the seller on any equipment. So first try to specify how legit it can be from your needs.

Comment: Yes, "hit and hold" is relatively common with solenoid valves. Some valve datasheets do say not to do it, while others encourage it by specifying a minimum hold current. In any case be generous with margins. Current control is something to look at too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing hysteresis on the operation of the valve and that is common with magnetic actuators.

Your approach is OK but be aware of a few points:

- You might need to be confident that a random spare from the same supplier will work over the same operating range. You might find that a replacement was not as sensitive and either wouldn't pick up or wouldn't hold up.
- Power dissipation will be \$ \frac {V^2} R \$ so reducing the voltage to 75% will result in a power reduction to 56%. There's no need to go as low as 3 V unless energy consumption is an issue.
- I didn't check the datasheet but if it's a regular pilot-operated valve then the solenoid opens the pilot air which moves the spool under air-pressure rather than direct magnet operation. You might find that the valve behaves differently with variations in pressure if the solenoid is not able to open the pilot fully.
- Related to the previous point, you might find that the valve switching response is different at lower voltage.
- Be sure to put a snubber diode around the coil.

Comment: Also note, if the unit experiences vibration or physical shock during operation, there will be less force available to maintain the current state (it could open or close.) Pressure/flow may further influence that behavior (when under-powered.)

Comment: OK, maybe I was too greedy with 3 V... If we take a look at the datasheet, it says that it can be controlled at -5% +10%. But -5% of 24 VDC is only 22.8 VDC which is not a great improvement... 75 % is 18 V. I don't know what to think of it : it will certainly work, but I am not within the specifications of the datasheet... :/